# Adding new content type with filtering and search options in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a wordpress theme to which I need to add a new content type with filtering and search options.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPT UI plugin is the plugin you're looking for.